# How to make unicode string with python3

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

I used this :

```
u = unicode(text, 'utf-8')
```

But getting error with Python 3 (or... maybe I just forgot to include something) :

```
NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined
```

Thank you.

Comment: If there's an awesome reason to upgrade to python 3 it is unicode by default.

Comment: ```text.encode('unicode_escape')``` would be enough I guess

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Literal strings are unicode by default in Python3.

Assuming that `text` is a `bytes` object, just use `text.decode('utf-8')`

`unicode` of Python2 is equivalent to `str` in Python3, so you can also write:

```
str(text, 'utf-8')
```

if you prefer.

Comment: TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: @Gank, In Python3 a `str` is unicode, ie. it is "decoded" so it makes no sense to call `decode` on it

Comment: Same TypeError. Please just replace with str(txt), or the code from @magicrebirth below

Comment: The original sample is not clear. So in python3, if you want to do `str(text, 'utf-8')`, text must be a string binary. e.g. `str(b'this is a binary', 'utf-8')`

Answer (score 12):

[What's new in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) says:

> All text is Unicode; however encoded Unicode is represented as binary
>   data

If you want to ensure you are outputting utf-8, here's an example from this page on [unicode in 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/howto/unicode.html):

```
b'\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", "strict")
```

Comment: this is exactly what we need for '\x80abc'.decode("utf-8", "strict") in Python 2, thanks

Answer (score 9):

As a workaround, I've been using this:

```
# Fix Python 2.x.
try:
    UNICODE_EXISTS = bool(type(unicode))
except NameError:
    unicode = lambda s: str(s)
```

Comment: Why are you using a lambda function? These methods are called the same way in any case. This is a simpler variation:

`try: unicode = str; except: pass`.

Comment: It seems like you can just do `unicode = str` since it won't fail in either 2 or 3

Comment: Or `from six import u as unicode` which I'd prefer simply because it's more self-documenting (since six is a 2/3 compatibility layer) than `unicode = str`

Answer (score 5):

This how I solved my problem to convert chars like \uFE0F, \u000A, etc. And also emojis that encoded with 16 bytes.

```
example = 'raw vegan chocolate cocoa pie w chocolate &amp; vanilla cream\\uD83D\\uDE0D\\uD83D\\uDE0D\\u2764\\uFE0F Present Moment Caf\\u00E8 in St.Augustine\\u2764\\uFE0F\\u2764\\uFE0F '
import codecs
new_str = codecs.unicode_escape_decode(example)[0]
print(new_str)
>>> 'raw vegan chocolate cocoa pie w chocolate &amp; vanilla cream\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d❤️ Present Moment Cafè in St.Augustine❤️❤️ '
new_new_str = new_str.encode('utf-16', errors='surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
print(new_new_str)
>>> 'raw vegan chocolate cocoa pie w chocolate &amp; vanilla cream❤️ Present Moment Cafè in St.Augustine❤️❤️ '
```

Comment: For more on 'surrogatepass' see https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers

Answer (score -1):

In a Python 2 program that I used for many years there was this line:

```
ocd[i].namn=unicode(a[:b], 'utf-8')
```

This did not work in Python 3.

However, the program turned out to work with:

```
ocd[i].namn=a[:b]
```

I don't remember why I put unicode there in the first place, but I think it was because the name can contains Swedish letters åäöÅÄÖ. But even they work without "unicode".