# unicode in python 3 gives NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to run a script in Python 3 that contains the line:

`yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]`

However, I keep getting this error:
`NameError: global name 'unicode' is not defined`

I have looked around, including here:
[How to make unicode string with python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812031/how-to-make-unicode-string-with-python3/6812069#6812069)

but the answers suggested haven't helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Repeating question - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812031/how-to-make-unicode-string-with-python3/6812069#6812069

Comment: What's the exception raised when you do `str(cell, 'utf-8')`?

Comment: `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`

Comment: Then `cell` is already a Unicode string.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall python and then re-install it. There is broken packages in python...