# Converting inconsistant encoding to utf-8 Python 3.4 BS 4.3

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to convert documents with inconsistent encoding to utf-8?

My project involves reading text from MS SQL 2000 (usually text or varchar),  'cleaning up' the text (stripping out style attributes, wrapping sections in divs) and inserting the 'clean' records into MySQL table.

I will often find text such as:

Important roads include King Faisal Highway on the northwestern side of the city, Al Fatih Highway on the eastern side, and Sh Isa Bin Salman Highway along the southern shore. Across the water on the nearby island of المحرق (Muharraq), highways 20 and 21 encircle the airport.

But get ??? after processing.

My code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as B_S, UnicodeDammit as U_D
import pymysql as db
import time

def mod_content():
    conn = db.connect( host='192.168.0.131', port=3306, user='USER', passwd='PASS', db='GRW', charset='utf8' )
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT city_id,nid,html_content,notes FROM content_city WHERE nid = 13 AND city_id = 182 ORDER BY city_id"
    c.execute( sql )
    for rec in c:
        contents = rec[2]
        contents = U_D.detwingle( contents )

        soup = B_S( contents )
        rs = soup.find_all( 'div', { 'class':'node_content' } )
        for r in rs:
            '''
            do clean up stuff
            '''
        contents = soup.prettify( formatter='html' ) # B_S function
        contents = ' '.join( contents.split() )
        ##### writing to a txt file here, but would want to do a MySQL INSERT
        raw = open( 'raw_182_mod.txt', 'a', 4 ) # a - append r - read w - write (writes over)
        raw.write( contents )
        raw.close()

    print( 'mod_content Complete' )

mod_content()
```

Is there a way to convert everything to utf-8?

UPDATE 3/24
So, according to this post ( [How to make unicode string with python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812031/how-to-make-unicode-string-with-python3) ) unicode of Python2 is str() in Python3. contents = str( contents, 'utf-8' ) gives me TypeErrors, and contents = contents.decode( 'utf-8' ) gives me AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. So, how do I incorporate this into my workflow?

```
def mod_content():
    conn = db.connect( host='192.168.0.131', port=3306, user='wtp', passwd='wtp', db='GRW', charset='utf8' )
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT city_id,nid,html_content,notes FROM content_city WHERE nid = 13 AND city_id = 182 ORDER BY city_id"
    c.execute( sql )
    print( 'type(c) is', type( c ) ) ## type(c) is <class 'pymysql.cursors.Cursor'>
    for rec in c:
        contents = rec[2]
        print( 'type(contents) is', type( contents ) ) ## type(contents) is <class 'str'>
        #print( contents ) ## this give's me ?????
        #contents = U_D.detwingle( contents )
        #contents = str( contents, 'utf-8' ) ## TypeError: decoding str is not supported


        soup = B_S( contents )
        print( 'type(soup) is', type( soup ) ) ## type(soup) is <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
        rs = soup.find_all( 'div', { 'class':'node_content' } )
        for r in rs:
            '''
            do clean up stuff
            '''
        #contents = str( contents, 'utf-8' ) ## TypeError: decoding str is not supported
        contents = soup.prettify( formatter='html' ) # B_S function
        contents = ' '.join( contents.split() )
        print( 'type(contents) AFTER prettify is', type( contents ) ) ## type(contents) AFTER prettify is <class 'str'>
        raw = open( 'raw_182_mod.txt', 'a', 4 ) # a - append r - read w - write (writes over)
        raw.write( contents )
        raw.close()

    print( 'mod_content Complete' )

mod_content()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 3/31
Here is how I solved this. If there is a better way, let me know

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as B_S
import pymysql as db
import time

def mod_content():

    conn = db.connect( host='192.xxx.x.xxx', port=3306, user='USER', passwd='PASSWORD', db='GRW', charset='utf8' ) ## declare charset
    c = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT city_id,nid,html_content,notes FROM content_city WHERE nid = 13 AND city_id = 182 ORDER BY city_id"
    c.execute( sql )

    for rec in c.fetchall():
        contents = rec[2]

        temp = B_S( contents)
        soup = temp.body

        allDivs = soup.find_all( 'div', { 'class':'picright' } )
        for div in allDivs:
            print( str( div )[ :80 ] )
            '''
            do clean up stuff
            '''

        # now, output the data. I end up with utf-8 string with ascii diacritics
        contents = soup.encode( 'ascii' )
        content_2str = contents.decode( 'utf-8' )
        content_2str = content_2str.replace( "'", "&#39;" ) ## single quotes replaced
        content_2str = ' '.join( content_2str.split() ) ## removes extra spaces and line breaks - now compacted  


        ## I can now print it to file or update MySQL
        if updateSQL == 'yes':

            sql = "UPDATE content_city SET html_content = '" + content_2str + \
            "',notes = '" + notes_2str + "' WHERE city_id = " + str( recID ) + \
            " AND nid = " + str( nid ) + ""

            c.execute( sql )
            conn.commit()


        if printToFile == 'yes':

            file2 = tempRoot + NIDs[ key ]+'_MOD.html'
            mod = open( file2, 'a',4 ) 

            mod.write( '\n' + str( nid ) + '\n' + str( recID ) + '\n' + \
                       content_2str + '\n' + notes_2str + '\n\n' )
            time.sleep(1)
            mod.close()



    print( 'mod_content Complete' )

mod_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

str1 = "Important roads include King Faisal Highway on the northwestern side of the city, Al Fatih Highway on the eastern side, and Sh Isa Bin Salman Highway along the southern shore. Across the water on the nearby island of المحرق (Muharraq), highways 20 and 21 encircle the airport."

**To convert text to unciode use**

```
 unicode(str1,"utf-8")

u'Important roads include King Faisal Highway on the northwestern side of the city, Al Fatih Highway on the eastern side, and Sh Isa Bin Salman Highway along the southern shore. Across the water on the nearby island of \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062d\u0631\u0642 (Muharraq), highways 20 and 21 encircle the airport.'
```

**To remove unicode from string use**

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(str1,"utf-8")).encode('ascii','ignore')

'Important roads include King Faisal Highway on the northwestern side of the city, Al Fatih Highway on the eastern side, and Sh Isa Bin Salman Highway along the southern shore. Across the water on the nearby island of  (Muharraq), highways 20 and 21 encircle the airport.'
```

Comment: Thanks. Your response led me to better understand Python3.4 str type. But your solution gives me errors in 3.4. See update above.