# How to convert list to unicode list

Tags: python, list, unicode

I have following list example

```
['Justice league', 'Avenger']
```

Now the problem i facing to convert list to unicode list 
Unicode list example is

```
[u'Justice league', u'Avenger']
```

How can I achieve this? thank you for your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try applying `unicode` to its elements

```
>>> lst=['Justice league', 'Avenger']
>>> map(unicode,lst)
[u'Justice league', u'Avenger']
```

Obviously we are talking about Python 2 only, since literal strings are unicode by default in Python 3

Have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812031/how-to-make-unicode-string-with-python3) on the same subject

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in `unicode` function with a list comprehension:

```
x = ['Justice league', 'Avenger']
answer = [unicode(item) for item in x]
```