# unicode python 3 equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x, translation, porting

I am currently trying to convert a piece of code from python 2 to python 3 and I cannot find the python 3 equivalent of `unicode`:

```
class NavigableString(unicode_literals, PageElement):

    def toEncoding(self, s, encoding=None):
    """Encodes an object to a string in some encoding, or to Unicode.
    ."""
    if isinstance(s, unichr()):
        if encoding:
            s = s.encode(encoding)
    elif isinstance(s, str):
        if encoding:
            s = s.encode(encoding)
        else:
            s = unicode_literals(s)
    else:
        if encoding:
            s  = self.toEncoding(str(s), encoding)
        else:
            s = unicode_literals(s)
    return s
```

Comment: ...which is to say that chances are good that all the code you're looking at here is unnecessary in Python 3 and can be removed outright rather than translated, unless you're starting from bytestrings rather than regular strings.

Comment: this might help. [how to make unicode strings with python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812031/how-to-make-unicode-string-with-python3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regular strings** in Python 3 are unicode. You have to go out of your way in Python 3 to get a bytestring (non-Unicode).