# 'utf-8' codec error while doc2vec

Tags: python, python-3.x

Unable to run the programme getting decode error. Actually, I am using gensim and trying Doc2vec library and while doing this I am getting this error? 
Code:-

```
def to_array(self):
    self.sentences = []
    for source, prefix in self.sources.items():
        with utils.smart_open(source) as fin:
            for item_no, line in enumerate(fin):
                self.sentences.append(LabeledSentence(
                    utils.to_unicode(line).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % 
item_no]))
    return self.sentences

sentences = LabeledLineSentence(sources)
model = Doc2Vec(min_count=1, window=10, size=100, dm_mean=0, sample=1e-5, 
negative=5, workers=12)
model.build_vocab(sentences.to_array())
```

Error:-

```
File "<ipython-input-88-eab20df20acc>", line 75, in <module>
model.build_vocab(sentences.to_array())

File "<ipython-input-88-eab20df20acc>", line 58, in to_array
utils.to_unicode(line).split(), [prefix + '_%s' % item_no]))

File "C:\Users\summert\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\gensim\utils.py", line 235, in any2unicode
return unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 21: 
invalid continuation byt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this anaconda gensim program is getting a byte when it wants utf-8. `model.build_vocab(sentences.to_array())` is not being fed the type it wants.

Where did you find `to_unicode` anyhow? Where was 'utils' imported from? I don't think that is regular Python 3. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812031/how-to-make-unicode-string-with-python3).

Given that you are using Python 3 you probably don't need anything there.

Just replace

```
(LabeledSentence(utils.to_unicode(line).split()...
```

with

```
(LabeledSentence(line.split()...
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
 (LabeledSentence(line.encode('utf-8').split()...
```