# how to check if an input is either a string or unicode in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, unicode, python-unicode

How do I check if someones input is either a string or unicode in my python  API program:

```
# POST: Add new item to data
# E.G. '{"title":"Read a book", "description":"Reading..."}'
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
    def create_task():
        if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
            abort(400)
        if 'title' in request.json and type(request.json['title']) != str:
            abort(400)
        if 'description' in request.json and type(request.json['description']) is not str:
            abort(400)
       task = {
            'id': tasks[-1]['id'] + 1,
            'title': request.json['title'],
            'description': request.json.get('description', ""),
            'done': False
        }
        tasks.append(task)
        return jsonify({'task': [make_public_task(task)]}), 201
```

the code that will have to change will need to be this bit:

```
if 'title' in request.json and type(request.json['title']) != str:
```

and

```
if 'description' in request.json and type(request.json['description']) is not str:
```

I tried

```
not in [str, unicode]:
```

but that didn't work.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `isinstance(request.json['description'], (str, unicode))`.

Comment: you have this tagged python-3 but all strings are unicode in python 3

Comment: Hi Willem, it states: 'NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined'

Comment: @JoeTilsed that's because it isn't, in python 3 all string literals are unicode by default

Comment: why are you trying to tell the difference? if you're worried about strings that aren't unicode you can stop worrying, they will all be unicode by default. if you need strings that aren't unicode you can cast them as such `str(string, 'utf-8')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812031/how-to-make-unicode-string-with-python3

Comment: Robbie, its when a user calls the API if they enter in a string or unicode, depending how they are calling the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it as follows:

```
if isintance(request.json.get('title'), basestring):
    ...
```

basestring is common ancestor for str and ucicode in Python 2.7. By using get instead of [] operator you can even get rid of `'title' in request.json` check

Comment: I am sorry, I have overlooked, that you want solution for python3. Correct answer should be then as follows:

    ```if isintance(request.json.get('title'), str):
        ...```

Comment: Okay, what would the code be like to call this API? my code below chucks a 500 error.

['code']

    import requests

    url = "http://localhost:8080/todo/api/v1.0/tasks"
    payload = '{"title":"Read a book", "description":"Reading..."}'
    requests.post(url, json=payload)

    print("Done...")

['code']

Comment: Figured it out, didn't need the ''

Comment: There's a typo "intance" instead of "instance"

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check if someones input is either a string or unicode in my python API program:

**No need to check**

You're writing in Python 3, so there's no such distinction in the first place - `unicode` no longer exists. You only have one kind of strings (`str`) and you have byte buffers (`bytes`) and for your problem `bytes` are not even relevant.

Looks like you're using Flask? Flask internally takes care of decoding network requests. By the time you asked about `request.json`, Flask already internally decoded the request with appropriate encoding and gave you a nice representation:

- json objects are of type `dict`
- json arrays are of type `list`
- json strings are of type `str` (I repeat - already decoded for you)
- json numbers are of type `int`
- json nulls are `None`

See? No `bytes`, don't worry about it now. You'll need to worry about `bytes` when dealing with raw data like file contents.