# encoding in strings in dataframe not recognized in Python

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a dataset that contains a dirty data in terms of wrong encoding:

example:

```
column_header,    other_column
Kol^u00edn,       ...
^u00d8lstykke,    ...
Aalborg S^u00d8,  ...
```

I used pandas to import the data (read_csv) and replaced the "^" with "" so it is the pythonic way of writing the unicode:

```
df["column_header"].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("^", "\\"))
```

which returns when printed:

```
0          Kol\u00edn
1       \u00d8lstykke
2     Aalborg S\u00d8
```

But what I need is not the python \u00ed but the unicode character í...

If I manually print("Kol\u00edn") I get Kolín, but it does not work in my dataframe.

How can I transform the strings in the dataframe to contain the actual character and not the \u... representation.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit:
Might be helpful:

```
print("Kol\u00edn".encode()) # returns b'Kol\xc3\xadn'
print(df["column_header"][0].encode()) # returns b'Kol\\u00edn'
```

Comment: what encoding you used while loading file, did your `iso-8859-1` ?

Comment: I did not specify any encoding when loading the data. The raw dataset is actually a dirty mixture of multiple combined datasets which had multiple encodings. E.g. I also have some strings that contain html characters like "&lt"...but i wanted to clean up the \u... stuff first.

I tried iso and utf-8 encoding when loading the data...same problem

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer by myself with the help of [this answer][1]:

```
import codecs
df["column_header"].apply(lambda x: codecs.unicode_escape_decode(x.replace("^", "\\"))[0])

# 1. replace all ^ by \
# 2. use codecs library which transforms raw string to unicode string
# "Kol\u00edn" --> u"Kol\u00edn" (the u"" is the key for python to recognize it)
```

maybe someone else has a similar problem and this helps
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57660758/9145756