# How to remove u' when running pandas' df.columns function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a data frame as shown below.

df:

```
id         fcb         psg         rma
1          4.0         2.9         4.1
2          3.5         4.2         3.5
3          2.5         4.5         4.0
4          4.1         4.6         4.2
```

I desired to see all of the ratings in a single column. So I ran the code below.

```
df.set_index(['id']).apply(dict, axis=1).reset_index(name='ratings')
```

However, I obtained the following results. But I wanted to remove the letter 'u" from all of the keys in each dictionary.

```
id  ratings
1   {u'fcb': 4.0, u'psg': 2.9, u'rma': 4.1}
2   {u'fcb': 3.5, u'psg': 4.2, u'rma': 3.5}
3   {u'fcb': 2.5, u'psg': 4.5, u'rma': 4.0}
4   {u'fcb': 4.1, u'psg': 4.6, u'rma': 4.2}
```

Expected output:

```
id  ratings
1   {'fcb': 4.0, 'psg': 2.9, 'rma': 4.1}
2   {'fcb': 3.5, 'psg': 4.2, 'rma': 3.5}
3   {'fcb': 2.5, 'psg': 4.5, 'rma': 4.0}
4   {'fcb': 4.1, 'psg': 4.6, 'rma': 4.2}
```

I tried below code to eliminate leading unicode in each keys.

```
df['rec_dict'] = df['rec_dict'].apply(lambda x: {str(k[1:]): v for k, v in x.items()})
```

Comment: Well that u just tells you the data type it wont affect in exports or data manipulation. But if it annoys you enough you can change the data type using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html. And you can see the data type using https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-check-the-data-type-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Are you using python2? If not, you can just ignore these unicode strings.

Comment: @mozway I am doing this in python 3.

Comment: @Danish well, it shouldn't show you the `u`, maybe your editor is showing that? In any case, just ignore it, all is unicode in python 3.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
df = df.set_index(['id']).apply(dict, axis=1).reset_index(name='ratings')
df['ratings'] = df['ratings'].apply(lambda x: {float(k[1:]): v for k, v in x.items()})
```

The first line is the same as your original code, but the second line uses the apply() function along with a lambda function to iterate over each dictionary in the 'ratings' column, and for each key-value pair, it converts the key from a string to a float and removes the 'u' from the beginning of the key. The resulting dictionary is then assigned back to the corresponding row in the 'ratings' column.

Comment: Your concept and explanations are excellent. Could you please share the results? Because I am not receiving the expected results. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: I tried below code but it is not removing unicode.

df['rec_dict'] = df['rec_dict'].apply(lambda x: {str(k[1:]): v for k, v in x.items()})

Answer (score 1):

`u'string'` denotes a unicode string in Python. Since Python 3 all strings have unicode encoding by [default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6812069/18281361). So you can safely ignore the notation.